# Understanding the shape of tensorflow placeholders

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow

I am reading [this code](https://github.com/openai/pixel-cnn/blob/master/train.py) and I would like to understand about its implementation.

---

One of the first things that I would like to know, is that what is the shape of some tensor objects (placeholders) such as `x_init`, `xs`, `h_init`, `y_init`, `y_sample`, etc.

I wrote a line of code such as `print(xs.shape)` but it wont work.

How can I understand the shape of these parameters (tensors)? And can I write something like the following in NumPy?

---

The part of code that defines these tensors look like this:

```
x_init = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(args.init_batch_size,) + obs_shape)

xs = [tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(args.batch_size, ) + obs_shape)
      for i in range(args.nr_gpu)]


# if the model is class-conditional we'll set up label placeholders +
# one-hot encodings 'h' to condition on if args.class_conditional:

num_labels = train_data.get_num_labels()
y_init = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(args.init_batch_size,))
h_init = tf.one_hot(y_init, num_labels)
y_sample = np.split(
    np.mod(np.arange(args.batch_size * args.nr_gpu), num_labels), args.nr_gpu)
h_sample = [tf.one_hot(tf.Variable(
    y_sample[i], trainable=False), num_labels) for i in range(args.nr_gpu)]
```

Comment: Please take time to format code yourself. You already have some reputation, you should be aware how things on this site run (post a well-formatted question is one of those things).

Comment: You can write in numpy but how would you compute the gradients of the loss function wrt to all the parameters? Or have you already done that?

Comment: @kmario23 I didnt mean writing the whole program in numpy. just these definitions of xs, ys, hs, etc in numpy so I can understand why they use these parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shape is assembled from different command line parameters:

- `obs_shape` is the shape of the input images, e.g., `(32, 32, 3)`
- `args.init_batch_size` and `args.batch_size` are the values from command line. It could be for example `30` and `40`.

Then shape of `x_init` is the concatenation of `init_batch_size` and  `obs_shape`: `(30, 32, 32, 3)`. Correspondingly, the shape of each item in `xs` is `(40, 32, 32, 3)`.

You couldn't evaluate `xs.shape`, because `xs` is a *list* of placeholders. You can evaluate `xs[0].shape` instead.

`y_sample` and `h_sample` are the lists of tensors as well. The first one contains `(batch_size, num_labels)` tensors, the second one `(num_labels, )`.